# Listen to window.onmessage in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to listen for a postmessage in my react class.  It isn't working.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener("onmessage", this.handleMessage);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('onmessage', this.handleMessage);
  }
  handleMessage(e){
    console.log('me?')
  }
}
```

I send the message like this:

```
window.opener.postMessage('a message', '*');
```

I know the message is getting to the window, because I can successfully listen to it in the plain JS file that loads the react app. However listening for it in react as above does not work.

Why isn't my listener every being triggered, how can I debug it?

Comment: Make sure that when you send the message the App component is mounted

Comment: Also the addEventListener should be message not onmessage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event's name should be `message` and not `onmessage`:

```
 window.addEventListener("message", this.handleMessage);
```

See: [The dispatched event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: yes! i just figured it out during a walk round the block.  good spot.